# What is the basic collection type in Scala?

Tags: scala, types, collections

Or in other words what is the equivalent of C# IEnumerable<T> in Scala? I thought it is Seq[T], but I already found out, that HashMap does not implement this, so it cannot be true.

So, what is it?

Comment: `HashMap` does implement `Seq`. Maybe you were looking at `java.util.HashMap`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`Traversable` and `Iterable` are base traits for scala collections. Actually, `Iterable` extends `Traversable`.

From scala api doc for `Iterable`:

> A base trait for iterable collections.
>
> This is a base trait for all Scala collections that define an **iterator**
>   method to step through one-by-one the collection's elements.

And `Traversable`:

> This is a base trait of all kinds of Scala collections. It implements
>   the behavior common to all collections, in terms of a method
>   **foreach**.

Here is a nice pics from [scala-lang site](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_1.html) that represents scala collections hierarchy (mutable and immutable respectively):

[image]

Immutable:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much (now I found it using google images :-) http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_1.html .

Comment: and Traversable extends TraversableOnce (which unites Iterator and Traversable) and TraversableOnce extends GenTraversableOnce (which units the sequential collections and the parallel.)