# What does the ++: operator do to a list?

Tags: scala

Alright, Scala has me feeling pretty dense. I'm finding the docs pretty impenetrable -- and worse, you can't Google the term "Scala ++:" because Google drops the operator terms!

I was reading some code and saw this line:

```
Seq(file) ++: children.flatMap(walkTree(_))
```

But couldn't figure it out. The docs for `Seq` show three things:

```
++
++:
++:
```

Where the latter two are over loaded to do.. something. The actual explanation in the doc says that they do the same thing as `++`. Namely, add one list to another.

So, what exactly is the difference between the operators..?

Comment: Use [symbolhound](http://www.symbolhound.com) to search symbols like that.

Comment: Google is fixed now! I came here by a search for `Scala ++:`. :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`++` and `++:` return different results when the operands are different types of collection. `++` returns the same collection type as the left side, and `++:` returns the same collection type as the right side:

```
scala> List(5) ++ Vector(5)
res2: List[Int] = List(5, 5)

scala> List(5) ++: Vector(5)
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(5, 5)
```

There are two overloaded versions of `++:` solely for implementation reasons. `++:` needs to be able to take any `TraversableOnce`, but an overloaded version is provided for `Traversable` (a subtype of `TraversableOnce`) for efficiency.

Answer (score 5):

Just to make sure:

A colon (:) in the end of a method name makes the call upside-down.

Let's make two methods and see what's gonna happen:

```
object Test {
  def ~(i: Int) = null
  def ~:(i: Int) = null //putting ":" in the tail!

  this ~ 1   //compiled
  1 ~: this  //compiled
  this.~(1)  //compiled
  this.~:(1) //compiled.. lol

  this ~: 1  //error
  1 ~ this   //error
}
```

So, in `seq1 ++: seq2`, `++:` is actually the `seq2`'s method.

edited: As @okiharaherbst mentions, this is called as *right associativity*.

Answer (score 1):

Scala function naming will look cryptic unless you learn a few simple rules and their precedence.

In this case, a colon means that the function has *right associativity* as opposed to the more usual left associativity that you see in imperative languages.

So `++:` as in `List(10) ++: Vector(10)` is not *an operator on the list* but a function called **on the vector** even if it appears on its left hand-side, i.e., it is the same as `Vector(10).++:(List(10))` and returns a *vector*.

`++` as in `List(10) ++ Vector(10)` is now function called on the list (left associativity), i.e., it is the same as `List(10).++(Vector(10))` and returns a *list*.

Comment: This right-associativity can be very confusing when you combine it into `++:=`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53332346/14955

Answer (score 0):

> what exactly is the difference between the operators..?

The kind of list a [`Seq.++`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Seq) operates on.

```
def ++[B](that: GenTraversableOnce[B]): Seq[B]
def ++:[B >: A, That](that: Traversable[B])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Seq[A], B, That]): That
def ++:[B](that: TraversableOnce[B]): Seq[B]
```

As commented in "[What is the basic collection type in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7745288/6309)"

- [`Traversable`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Traversable) extends [`TraversableOnce`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.TraversableOnce) (which unites `Iterator` and `Traversable`), and
- [`TraversableOnce`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.TraversableOnce) extends [`GenTraversableOnce`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce) (which units the sequential collections and the parallel.)