# Why is the ++: operator in the Scala language so strange?

Tags: arrays, scala, collections, assignment-operator

I am using the `++:` operator to get a collection of two collections, but the results I get using these two methods are inconsistent:

```
scala> var r = Array(1, 2)
r: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2)
scala> r ++:= Array(3)
scala> r
res28: Array[Int] = Array(3, 1, 2)

scala> Array(1, 2) ++: Array(3)
res29: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)
```

Why do the `++:` and `++:=` operators give different results?
This kind of difference does not appear with the `++` operator.

The version of Scala I am using is 2.11.8.

Comment: Another interesting effect of `++:` and `++:=` is that it takes the type of the result collection from the right-hand side (in case they are not both Arrays as here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/24338494/14955) --- for some definition of "right-hand" in the presence of `++:=`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since it ends in a colon, `++:` is right-associative. This means that `Array(1, 2) ++: Array(3)` is equivalent to `Array(3).++:(Array(1, 2))`. `++:` can be thought of as "prepend the elements of the left array to the right array."

Since it's right-associative, `r ++:= Array(3)` desugars to `r = Array(3) ++: r`. This makes sense when you consider that the purpose of `++:` is prepending. This desugaring holds true for any operator that ends in a colon.

If you want to append, you can use `++` (and `++=`).

Comment: @Thilo [`+:`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/GenSeqLike.html#+:(elem:A):scala.collection.GenSeq[A]), [`::`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#::(x:A):List[A]), and [`:::`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#:::(prefix:List[A]):List[A]) come to mind. Again, it's anything that ends in a colon.

Comment: @Thilo: There is no such thing as an "operator" in Scala. Any method can be called without a period like this: `a foo(bar, baz)`, and when you are passing only one argument, you can leave out the parenthesis like this: `a foo bar`. That's it. It's just a normal method call, and `++` is just a normal method name like `foo`. There are two exceptions, though, that mean that Scala actually *does* have "half-operators". 1) Precedence is determined by the first character of the method name. 2) Methods ending in a `:` are right-associative when called with operator syntax.

Comment: Note: this also applies to Type Constructors. So, if you have `class Foo[A, B] {}`, then you can of course say `def foo: Foo[Int, String]`, but you can also say `def foo: Int Foo String`, and if you have `class Foo_:[A, B]`, then `Foo_:[Int, String]` is the same as `String Foo_: Int`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag The bit about type constructors is wild. I know that Scalaz uses it for a pretty "Either" (`def foo: String \/ Int`). Are there examples of someone doing a right-associative type ?

Comment: @Thilo: You don't realize it, but you probably have seen it already, although it's not actually exposed to the user: `::` is a method on `List`, an object, and also a class. But you are normally dealing with `List`, not with `::`.

Comment: Ah, sorry. My bad. `::` is unary, not binary. But probably someone is doing that.

Comment: @Thilo [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) has a binary `::` type constructor. Since it is right-associative, `Int :: String :: HNil` is equivalent to `::[Int, ::[String, HNil]]`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Type constructors can be right-associative (`shapeless.::` is an example), but they don't swap the order of their arguments in that case (thankfully).

Answer (score 0):

Here colon(**:**) means that the function has right associativity

so, for instance  `coll1 ++: coll2` is similar to `(coll2).++:(coll1)`

Which generally means the elements of the left collection is prepended to right collection

**Case-1:**

```
Array(1,2) ++: Array(3)
Array(3).++:Array(1,2) 
Elements of the left array is prepended to the right array 
so the result would be Array(3,1,2)
```

**Case-2:**

```
 r = Array(1,2)
 r ++:= Array(3) //This could also be written as the line of code below
 r = Array(3) ++: r
   = r. ++: Array(3)
   = Array(1,2). ++: Array(3) //Elements of the left array is prepended to the right array 
 so their result would be Array(1,2,3)
```

Hope this solves the query
Thank you :)

Comment: `++:` is a method, not a function.